# SO tag display inconsistent

Tags: feature-request, bug

On SO, I typically have something like

> [delphi] or [pascal]

in the search box to the right of the Stack Overflow logo.

However, the same screen summarizes this as

> Public questions tagged [delphi or pascal]

Is there any point to this inconsistency, or is it just a mistake?

Comment: I've shared this on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311173/369403) on the new nav thread (both because it's a mess when searching for many tags, and because they're no longer distinct).